# JUnit - Postponed assert failure

Tags: testing, junit, automated-tests

I'm automating functional tests using JUnit. And I ran into a problem: if I follow the rule "one (significant) assert per test method" then I end up with a bunch of 6-line test methods per one test case (17 is the biggest number yet). If I put them all into one test method I have to comment out failing asserts or leave half of the test never launched.

I don't like the first way because it launches browser for too many times, and it appears that browser launch + login/logout are more "expensive" and time consuming than test run itself.

The second way is no better because it introduces a lot of manual work in any case of managing it.

So, my questions are:
1. What are the best practices for such cases? 
2. Is there some way to postpone test failure till the end of test? I mean, less important assert, that doesn't stop test run but causes it to fail in the end nonetheless.

UPD: Yes, I'm using Selenium. And I have a parent class for every test class to unify their settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass to launch and shutdown the Browser once for each test class or you can create a Rule that launches your Browser and use it with @ClassRule.
2. [ErrorCollector](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was looking for something like ErrorCollector. Hopefully, I haven't started to invent my own bicycle to do that :) Can you recommend some tutorial or examples on using it?

Comment: There's only the JavaDoc, but if you provide your current test, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass(){

    launchBrowser();

}

@Before
public void before() {

    login();

}

@AfterClass
public static void beforeClass(){

    killBrowser();

}
```

That could be the answer to your problem

Comment: Thank you, that can do in some cases. But BeforeClass and AfterClass methods demand static variables - so, browser instance should be static for this.  I plan to launch tests in parallel in the nearest future. This can mess everything up.

Comment: At the time I accomplish that by launching the browser in the constructor in each class

Comment: And have a driver instance per class. Are we talking about Selenium? Maybe you can add that to your question thx

Comment: I'm launching browser once for every test method.

Comment: I can't understand that. If you open a driver/method you will loose more time opening and killing browsers than for testing!? And what should that be good for?

Comment: I'm going to launch tests in parallel. Static browser won't allow me to do that. I can't see other way of launching browser.

Comment: you launch methods in parallel? never did that but it's possible to use as much webdrivers as threads and release them after each test.. but if you have as much threads as tests that wont work for you